# How to draw squares around objects in image and count them?

Tags: python, image, object-recognition

So, I made a (hopefully good) model in python for apples; I used a dataset from Kaggle that had a bunch of pictures of apples upclose, and trained it to recognize them with accuracy of around 85%.

My question now is how do I use that model to draw squares around apples from my picture and count them, for example a box of apples?

Comment: [mre] please... and please also review [ask]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.